# Value of emitted events in App.js

Tags: solidity, truffle, blockchain, javascript, ethereumj

Actually in my App.js I have called my contract function like this:

```
[ 
this.state.swapcontract.methods.sendFunds(address).send({ from: this.state.account , value:amount}) 
]
```

The function is called perfectly and does the work correctly but it also emits an event.

How do I access that event in my app.js?

Also if some function returned something then how to access it also?

Also this is not a async call and the call back function which many sites suggest is doing nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function `send` returns a `Promise` object which, when resolved, returns the transaction-receipt.

The transaction-receipt contains all events emitted by your contract function (`sendFunds`).

**So first, save that `Promise` object:**

```
const promise = this.state.swapcontract.methods.sendFunds(address).send(...);
```

Then, resolve it in order to get the receipt.

**You can do so by calling this from an `async` function:**

```
const receipt = await promise;
console.log(JSON.stringify(receipt, null, 4));
```

**Or by calling this from anywhere:**

```
promise.then(function(receipt) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(receipt, null, 4));
});
```

Finally, read the printout in order to learn exactly where the events are stored within the receipt.